# SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND variable not getting set

Tags: ssh, freebsd, ssh-keys, jail

I am working with two servers, both of which run FreeBSD 8.4-RELEASE-p1 and OpenSSH_6.1p1. Both servers' `ssh_config` files, located in `/etc/ssh`, are identical. Both servers are configured to allow users to remote into a jailed environment using SSH.

As a test, I logged into a test user's jail using SSH keys on both servers, using the following command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/private_key test-user@server.mydomain.com hello
```

And the `authorized_keys` file in both cases specifies the following command to be run after authentication, prepended to the public key (permissions are the same on both servers):

```
command="~/test.sh",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty
```

Where `test.sh`simply performs the following operation:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND = $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

On one server, the output from the above `sh` script shows the following:

```
SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND = hello
```

But on the other server, the result appears not to get stored in SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND

```
SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND =
```

The behavior is the same for the respective server for each user jail. My question is - what other configuration would I need to allow the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` variable to be set after authentication in the case of the second server?

Comment: Try to add `env` command to test.sh to see if other SSH_* variables are set

Comment: Thanks. It appears that the `env` command is not accessible via the user jails.

Comment: Have you compared the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` files on both servers?

Comment: If you put `env |grep -i ssh` into that second server's test.sh script, what environment variables are found?  Is there a difference between SSH server versions or configurations on the two systems?

Comment: @Dylan: If `env` is not available, you can use `set` with similar success. It is a shell built-in and would work inside the jail.

Comment: It seems that SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND is set if you have a forced command. Do both servers actually read the authorized_keys file?
 https://sources.debian.net/src/openssh/1:7.5p1-5/session.c/

Answer (score 1):

Look in /etc/profile and other init scripts (~/.bashrc etc) - those are some things which set environment variables.

Remember that you need a ". " in place of scripts if you want their environment settings they set up to "stick".